# How to hide a website from browser history completely?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So here is the backstory on why I would want to do this.

The website I am working on is a harbor for abuses people, wife, men, etc. People who are looking for help and being abused. These abusers sometimes threaten to kill the person if they ever thought about leaving and if this website was in the browser history could harm the person viewing the website.

My goal would be to one, hide the website completely from history or two, at least have the titles that are reported in the history named something different. "Cuddly kittens" Something that wouldn't arouse suspicion.

I have read this is not possible and I have read other stating that you can manipulate the recent history. Having the ability to hide the website completely from History would be best.

Thank you.

Comment: A noble reason, but unfortunately it's not possible from the website's side. It's down to the user to delete their history. Perhaps you could include a guide on the site on exactly how you do that in various different browsers.

Comment: You could always set your HTML `<title>` field to be something like `http://www.cuddlykittens.com`. Then it would look as though the site were that in the history or bookmarks... but I wouldn't *rely* on that.

Comment: This is not even accomplishable through Javascript. Not exactly the answer you were looking for, but you could use the same back-end to drive two different front-ends. One could be skinned and branded for the public; available on your proper domain. The other front end could hide in plain sight; buy a domain like `cutecatpics.com` and skin your site to match. Page titles and domain will be logged in history, but the content will not. Provided a user is logged in, they will see the real content of the site?

Comment: Highlight to your users that they can use *"private window"* or (name depends on browser) *"incognito window"*  feature in modern browsers which keeps no history or cookies

Comment: Thank you for all of your responses. @MattClark I was thinking of the idea you are referring to. I thought about this but at the same time I think if they were going to get to the website first, then they would be better off being directed with a guide how to delete history and open a private window. At least this is my thought. 
What, in your opinion, would be the best button to use as an escape key. I know I can't close the entire window, though I thought I would make a static page, that could load quickly in case the "abuser" were to walk up on them viewing the website. I'm thinking F9.

Comment: That is entirely up to you; just make sure whichever key you choose can be hooked via JavaScript. Clear history is a good idea, but in my opinion, not really the best option. Missing web history might be more suspect then CuteCatPics. The malicious party could also have software that tracks browsing history independent of the web browser, now these logs will be mismatched and could draw suspicion.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try using `document.location.replace()` it is used to clear the last entry in the history and replace it with the address of a new url. replace() removes the URL of the current document from the document history, meaning that it is not possible to use the "back" button to navigate back to the original document.